# Flink 1.2.1 - How to create a savepoint when Flink is running in containers?

Tags: docker, containers, apache-flink, docker-swarm

I have Flink 1.2.1 running on Docker, with Task Managers distributed across different VMs as part of a Docker Swarm.

I understand Dynamic Scaling is not yet available in Flink. Therefore, if I wanted to increase the number of containers running Flink's task manager (scale up), I would need to create a savepoint, stop the running job, scale up my Task Manager containers, then resume the job.

My question is: how do I create a savepoint? The documentation assumes you are using the Command Line Client, but I don't think I can access it if I am running Flink in containers. The Web UI doesn't allow you to create savepoints either. What do I do, in this case?

I am using the official Flink documentation as reference:
https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.2/setup/cli.html#savepoints

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I think I may have found an answer to my own question. I'll post it here in case there are other people in the future struggling with the same issue.

Basically, I used the 'docker exec' command to get inside the container running Job Manager and execute commands in that container.

The scaling process is a bit convoluted, but here's what works for me:

1. Obtain ID of the container running Job Manager:
   `JOBMANAGER_CONTAINER=$(docker ps --filter name=jobmanager --format={{.ID}})`
2. Cancel the current job and create a savepoint:
   `docker exec -t -i "$JOBMANAGER_CONTAINER" flink cancel -s   [savepointDirectory] <jobID>`
3. Copy the name of the savepoint created.
4. Scale taskmanager.
5. In the Web-UI, submit the job again specifying the new parallelism and the path of the savepoint created above.

Until dynamic scaling is available with Flink, the process above should work. I haven't tested it in a Swarm environment yet, but it scales fine with Docker Compose.

Comment: Hi, is it still the approach you are following with savepoints on docker?